# Why this code is not working in CSOM: "new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext)"

Tags: client-object-model

This is the code which is not working. I have this code in my dispForm.aspx.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var personProperties;
    function getUserProperties() 
    {   
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

        personProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();

        clientContext.load(personProperties);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
    }

    function onRequestSuccess() 
    {       
      alert(personProperties.get_displayName());
      alert(personProperties.get_pictureUrl());
      alert(personProperties.get_loginName());
    }

    function onRequestFail(sender, args) 
    {
      alert("error msg");
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to work with User Profiles JSOM API, `SP.UserProfiles.js` library have to be loaded first. Since [SP.SOD.executeFunc method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409592.aspx) supports load on demand scripts, use it to make sure the library `SP.UserProfiles.js` is loaded.

The following example demonstrates how to initialize `PeopleManager` object:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
   // Make sure PeopleManager is available 
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('userprofile', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', function() {

      var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

      //...

   });

});
```

In your case you could invoke `getUserProperties` method like this:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.UserProfiles.js','SP.UserProfiles',getUserProperties);
```

> Note: there is a typo I guess on line:
>
> ```
> alert(personProperties.get_loginName());
> ```
>
> `SP.UserProfiles.PersonProperties` does not contain property named
>   `LoginName`, but does contain `AccountName`:
>
> ```
> var accountName = personProperties.get_accountName();
> ```

Comment: `executeFunc()` does not rely on the scripts to load prior to executing the functions, and "if the script associated with the script key is already loaded, then executeFunc does absolutely NOTHING", according to https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/key-points-to-know-when-using-sp-sod-executefunc-and-sp-sod-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded/ - better to use `executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can most likely get results using the API.

```
_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

Sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', GetMyUserProfileProperties);
});

GetMyUserProfileProperties = function () {

    var firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    workEmail = "";
    workPhone = "";

    //Get the current user's account information
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +
            "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (data) {

            try {
                //Get properties from user profile Json response
                //userDisplayName = data.d.DisplayName;
                //pictureUrl = data.d.PictureUrl;
                var properties = data.d.UserProfileProperties.results;
                for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
                    var property = properties[i];
                    if (property.Key == "FirstName") {
                        firstName = property.Value;
                    }
                    if (property.Key == "LastName") {
                        lastName = property.Value;
                    }
                    if (property.Key == "WorkEmail") {
                        workEmail = property.Value;
                    }
                    if (property.Key == "WorkPhone") {
                        workPhone = property.Value;
                    }
                }

                window.console && console.log(firstName);
                window.console && console.log(lastName);
                window.console && console.log(workEmail);
                window.console && console.log(workPhone);

            } catch (err2) {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(err2));
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Nice null-shielding trick with window.console && :) +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to load `'SP.UserProfiles.js'` file in orde to work with user profiles in SharePoint javascript client object model.  Example:

```
var personProperties;

// Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');

function getUserProperties() {

    // Replace the placeholder value with the target user's credentials.
    var targetUser = "domainName\\userName";

    // Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    // Get user properties for the target user.
    // To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the
    // getMyProperties method.
    personProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(targetUser);

    // Load the PersonProperties object and send the request.
    clientContext.load(personProperties);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds.
function onRequestSuccess() {

    // Get a property directly from the PersonProperties object.
    var messageText = " \"DisplayName\" property is "
        + personProperties.get_displayName();

    // Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
    messageText += "<br />\"Department\" property is "
        + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Department'];
    $get("results").innerHTML = messageText;
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
    $get("results").innerHTML = "Error: " + args.get_message();
}
```

Source:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: I still get Error: Unable to get property 'PeopleManager' of undefined or null reference. Do I need to configure something in my user profile service application?

Comment: Do you have permissions to access the User Profile service application

Comment: I am logged in with my account. My account is site collection administrator.

Comment: Add this above the `SP.SOD...` line, to run onload:  `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadSPUserProfiles, 'sp.js');` - then put the `SP.SOD...` line he has there inside a new `function loadSPUserProfiles() { ... }` -- `sp.js` needs to load first, then `SP.UserProfiles.js`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that both `sp.js` and `SP.UserProfiles.js` need to be loaded in order for the user profile to be accessible.  To ensure this, use `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(functionToRun, 'scriptToLoadFirst.js')`.

If you include a reference to jQuery, you can run a `document.ready` routine to load the `sp.js`, which in turn calls a function where you can load `SP.UserProfiles.js`, and then the ultimate function that is loading the profile data, for which I switch over to ECMAScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadSPUserProfiles, 'sp.js');
    });

    function loadSPUserProfiles() {
        SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/ECMAScript">
    var personProperties;
    function getUserProperties() 
    {   
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);
        personProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();
        clientContext.load(personProperties);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
    }

    function onRequestSuccess() 
    {       
        var accountName = personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['AccountName'];
        var preferredName = personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['PreferredName'];
        var pic = personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['PictureURL'];

        alert(accountName);
        alert(preferredName);
        alert(pic);

        // BONUS - For picture URLs....
        var html;
        var imglink;
        if (pic != "") {
            // Note:  If uploaded, a picture URL will look like this:
            // <a href="http://www.domain.com/mysite/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/username_MThumb.jpg">http://www.domain.com/mysite/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/username_MThumb.jpg</a>';
            // So if we just want the URL so we can put it in a new IMG tag with a new hyperlink to their profile:
            var res = pic.indexOf(">");
            imglink = pic.substring(res+1, pic.length);
            imglink = imglink.replace("</a>","");
            alert(imglink);
            // Making a link to their profile:
            html =  "<a href='/mysites/person.aspx'><img src='" + imglink + "'/></a><br>";
        } else {
            // If a picture has not been uploaded, it doesn't exist -
            // Use this, instead:
                    var url = window.location.href.split('/');
                    var baseUrl = url[0] + "/" + url[1] + "/" + url[2];
                    imglink = baseUrl + "/_layouts/15/images/PersonPlaceholder.96x96x32.png";
            html = "<a href='/mysites/person.aspx'><img src='" + imglink + "'/></a><br>";
        }
        $('[id*="piclink"]').append(html);
    }

    function onRequestFail(sender, args) 
    {
        alert("error msg");
    }

</script>
<html><body>
    <div id="piclink"></div>
</body></html>
```

I've seen people say to use `SP.executeFunc`.  You actually want to avoid using `SP.executeFunc` because, as [this link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/key-points-to-know-when-using-sp-sod-executefunc-and-sp-sod-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded/) states:

> ...it’s very similar to the `executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` function, but the key difference is that if the script associated with the script key is not loaded, `executeFunc` loads the script and executes the delegate method.  This is fine and good and exactly what I would expect.  What I believe to be odd is that if the script associated with the script key is already loaded, then `executeFunc` does absolutely NOTHING.  I assumed it would run the delegate method if the script was already loaded, but that is apparently not the case.

From that account, it actually is bad on two fronts:

1. Loading the script file may not happen prior to the delegate code launching, as they happen asynchronously.
2. As the author states, if the script file is already loaded, the delegate code is not launched.

So using `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` is the safer bet, and would need to happen for each JavaScript library:  `sp.js` and `SP.UserProfiles.js`.

**One other note - using field names instead of methods**

I prefer using the field name in brackets (`get_userProfileProperties()['somefieldname']`) to get the field value than `get_somefieldname`.  I don't necessarily want to rely on the method being available and have to rememember what it's called, when I know what the field is called and know that it should be there because it's storing my data.  It's also easier to look up the exact field name in the User Profile Service Application within Central Administration.  And often the field names and the method names are different, so then there's that to worry about - whereas the field names I see as more intuitive and easier to find out - the method names, not so much.

**Bonus material - Picture URLs**

Since I saw the `PictureURL` was being retrieved, I thought I would add this material.  A picture URL, when a picture is uploaded for the user and the URL is filled in, will have a hyperlink to itself, along with the address of the picture.  If you only just want the URL itself, it requires splicing it out - so I've included that code above as a "bonus".  But because picture URLs might be empty if they have not uploaded a new one (which could lead one to believe the call didn't work, but it just actually doesn't have anything to display), I've included code to the default picture to help anyone out with translating them out to what they should be if empty.  I've also included appending a DIV with the link so a person can see how it looks if it were added to a page.  And, to me, it's more useful for the link to go to the user's profile page than the image, so my hyperlinks above include `'/mysites/person.aspx'`, and this would obviously be different and need to change based on where your mysites are stored if you wished to do the same.